# Pillow Image functions not callable

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I am new to using python and for my first project, I decided to do something with Pillow. I had just started before I ran into this problem,
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Li/images/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(cookie.size())
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`
Here is my code,

```
from PIL import Image

cookie = Image.open("image.ppm")

print(cookie.size())
cookie.show()
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow and I am pretty sure I installed it correctly.
Please Help

Comment: `Image.size` is not a function; you can just use `print(cookie.size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(cookie.size())
```

`Image.size` is a field, not a function or method. Remove the parentheses:

```py
print(cookie.size)
```